# Python sqlite updating with json

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following query to update a column from a sqlite dataset.

```
rig_json = json.dumps(json.loads(f.read()))
query = """UPDATE session_rigs SET rig = '{}'  WHERE session = '{}'""".format(rig_json, session)
```

The dtype of `rig` column is `TEXT`, so I have to load the JSON file and convert it to a string. But this query gives me some error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "purged_parameter": syntax error
```

I tried something like this:

```
query = """UPDATE session_rigs SET rig = '{}'  WHERE session = '{}'""".format({"a":"b"}, session)
```

And it works fine.

Comment: what does your JSON look like, exactly?  It looks like you may just want to pass the raw JSON.

Comment: It is quite complex, has multiple layers of `dic`. 

How do I pass the raw JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have quoting problems.  Your string contains single quotes, which screws things up.  This is why you should not use Python string formatting to build your queries.  Let SQLite fix it.

```
rig_json = f.read()
query = "UPDATE session_rigs SET rig=? WHERE session=?;"
cur.execute( query, (rig_json, session) )
```

Also note that `json.dumps(json.loads(xxx))` is silly.  To pass that, it had to be valid JSON to begin with.  Just read the string.